# Unable to mount Audio Disc

Tags: 10.10, hardware, sound, cd-drive

When I insert an audio disc, I get this message:

```
Unable to mount Audio Disc
Location is not mountable
```

I use Ubuntu 10.10
What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a known bug: [Bug #609020](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/609020).

Workaround: Install [gvfs-backends](http://packages.ubuntu.com/gvfs-backends)

```
sudo apt-get install gvfs-backends
```

Comment: Added the file through Synaptic. Works now, thanks

Comment: Also helped solve the problem in 11.10