# "Unable to mount Audio Disc Location is unmountable" error

Tags: 10.10, multimedia, cd-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to mount Audio Disc](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18724/unable-to-mount-audio-disc)

I've lost use of my cdrom player in Ubuntu 10.10. The message is "Unable to mount Audio Disc  Location is unmountable". How can I correct this?

Comment: Could you add more detail, such as if the drive was working before, if normal CD's work, etc?

Comment: Also try cleaning the disc.

Comment: Could you post the output of `ls -la /media/cdrom` and `mount`?

Answer (score -1):

You usually don't mount audio discs. If you want to play one, use a media player. You should also be able to use whatever default ripping program you have. Pure audio discs don't have a file system that the standard linux drivers can mount. Instead, linux has drivers that allow other programs to access it as a special audio-cdrom device.

Comment: This is an error that comes up when you insert an audio CD. Semantic dithering over the term "mount" isn't helpful unless you're going to dig into the problem further -- eg. explain why Ubuntu might be trying to "mount" an audio CD when it should be doing something else with it.

Comment: @Amanda The user got a mount error. It isn't "semantic dithering" to explain the mount error. Furthermore, it isn't clear who is mounting the disc, Ubuntu or the user. I assumed the user had. I assumed Ubuntu would know better than to try unless forced by the user. John never came back to clarify his situation, and I wasn't aware until 18 hours ago that a similar question (with substantially more detail) had been asked and answered. **Downvote the badly formed question, not my earnest, useful answer.**